# I want to display name of subject in hint and then marks

Tags: android

This is my AddResult Activity where two function insert and update

```
public class AddResult extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText eng, urdu, math, bio, chem, phy, rol;
Database database;
Button btnsave;
int roll;
ArrayList<resultmodel> result;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_result);
    database = new Database(this);
    eng = findViewById(R.id.edsub1);
    urdu = findViewById(R.id.edsub2);
    math = findViewById(R.id.edsub3);
    phy = findViewById(R.id.edsub4);
    btnsave = findViewById(R.id.save);
    bio = findViewById(R.id.edsub5);
    chem = findViewById(R.id.edsub6);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    roll = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
    result = database.search(roll);
    if (result.size() > 0)
        updataData();
    else
        insertData();
}

public void insertData() {
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        ;
        String E = eng.getText().toString();
        String U = urdu.getText().toString();
        String M = math.getText().toString();
        String B = bio.getText().toString();
        String P = phy.getText().toString();
        String C = chem.getText().toString();
        if (E.equals("") || U.equals("") || M.equals("") || B.equals("") || P.equals("") || C.equals(""))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all field first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            int English = Integer.parseInt(E);
            int Bio = Integer.parseInt(B);
            int Math = Integer.parseInt(M);
            int Urdu = Integer.parseInt(U);
            int Physics = Integer.parseInt(P);
            int Chemistry = Integer.parseInt(C);
            resultmodel result = new resultmodel(English, Urdu, Math, Bio, Chemistry, Physics, roll);
            int i = database.resultInsertion(result);
            if (i == 1)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Result is inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            else

                Toast.makeText(this, "Result is not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is here

```
public void updataData() {
    btnsave.setText("UPDATE");
    resultmodel m = result.get(0);
    bio.setText(String.valueOf(m.getB()));
    chem.setText(String.valueOf(m.getC()));
    phy.setText(String.valueOf(m.getP()));
    urdu.setText(String.valueOf(m.getU()));
    eng.setText(String.valueOf(m.getE()));
    math.setText(String.valueOf(m.getM()));
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        String E = eng.getText().toString();
        String U = urdu.getText().toString();
        String M = math.getText().toString();
        String B = bio.getText().toString();
        String P = phy.getText().toString();
        String C = chem.getText().toString();
        if (E.equals("") || U.equals("") || M.equals("") || B.equals("") || P.equals("") || C.equals(""))
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please fill all field first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else {
            int English = Integer.parseInt(E);
            int Bio = Integer.parseInt(B);
            int Math = Integer.parseInt(M);
            int Urdu = Integer.parseInt(U);
            int Physics = Integer.parseInt(P);
            int Chemistry = Integer.parseInt(C);
            resultmodel result = new resultmodel(English, Urdu, Math, Bio, Chemistry, Physics, roll);
            Boolean b = database.updateresult(result);
            //Log.i("LogId", String.valueOf(b));
            if (b == true)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data is updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else

                Toast.makeText(this, "Result is not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

I am using one layout for insert marks and update. In my insert layout I have use EditText with hint.
To use this layout  for updating I have fill previous inserted data but this data show only subject marks. I want to show first subject Name in hint and then subject marks in text. For better understanding I have attach screen of my app

[image: This show confusing without subject name]

[image: This is my save layout]

Comment: `I want to show first subject Name in hint and then subject marks in text.` Where is the issue now? Do you want both hint and text?

Comment: yes I want both

Comment: Then why can't you use TextInputLayout? https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout

Answer (score 1):

[image: Sample]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
      android:layout_margin="8dp">

      <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/name"
            android:maxLength="80"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Use Material Edittext this will make your goal easy

Answer (score 0):

Use [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout) by adding this dependency

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

Sample layout for TextInputLayout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etSubject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_45"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dp_24"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dp_8"
        android:background="@drawable/floating_hint_margin"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:hint="@string/subject"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dp_10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textColorHint="@color/secondary_text"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sp_16" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

floating_hint_margin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="@dimen/dp_4">
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="0.8dp"
                android:color="@color/darkGrey" />
            <solid android:color="@color/whiteSecondary" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/dp_4" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```